# Serializing nested querysets from many-to-one relationships

Tags: django, postgresql, serialization, orm, django-queryset

I have a survey app, where there are surveys, questions, and choices to the questions. Each question has a foreign key to the survey it belongs to, and each choice has a foreign key to the question is belongs to. 
Cleaned out model code for a multiple choice question is shown below.

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    # survey attributes, not needed in the query for this question 

class Question(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    prompt = models.TextField()

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    letter = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    text = models.TextField()
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

To get all the questions in a survey, I can select all the data I need with the backwards relationship as such,

```
Survey.objects.get(pk=1).question_set\
.select_related('choice__text', 'choice__letter')\
.values('prompt', 'choice__text', 'choice__letter')
```

and It will return, as expected,

```
[{
    prompt: str, 
    choice__text: str,
    choice__letter: char, 
},]
```

...but this will duplicate the prompt in every row and ideally the formatting would be closer to

```
[{
    prompt: str,
    choice_set: [{
        letter: char,
        text: str,
    },]
},]
```

I have solved a similar problem before by throwing it in a panda dataframe and grouping the data before serializing, but I can only assume the creators of django made a way to do this

Is there any way to easily nest these queries without looping through each question model and querying for its choices?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Serializer from django-rest-framework should do the trick. Serializers can be nested like the example in the section "Nested relationships" on http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/relations